# clone an existing virtual machine from virtualbox using python

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I would like to write an application, which shall clone a virtual machine from virtualBox, which I installed separetly. I assume that I know where the vdi file is and can access it. I know also that I can install virtualbox manager and then execute the shell in python. However I am looking for and existing library/API that avoid me to go through permission stuffs with shell. I tried pyvbox but it did not work. A simple find doesn't get the machine.

```
 # I tried these two commands
 vm = vbox.find_machine('test_vm')
 vm2 = vbox.find_machine('path/to/test_vm')
```

I guess this is because the virtual machine test_vm is not registed to this instance. Any idea on how to do the cloning of already existing virtual machine from installed virtualbox?

Comment: IDK about pyvbox, but most `VBoxManage` shell commands want a machine UUIDs. Try `VBoxManage list vms`.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're following the [pyvbox documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/pyvbox/readme.html#getting-started), but perhaps not correctly?
This is what I did (win10, python 2.7):

```
>>> pip install pyvbox
>>> python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import virtualbox
>>> vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
>>> print("VM(s):\n + %s" % "\n + ".join([vm.name for vm in vbox.machines]))
VM(s):
 + tails2.4a
 + Kali-Linux-testvm
 + lubuntu1610
>>> vm = vbox.find_machine('lubuntu1610')
>>> vm
<virtualbox.library_ext.machine.IMachine object at 0x0000000002D069B0>
```

You refer to 'session', I think you mean:
`session = virtualbox.Session()`
which (merely initiates a virtualbox session)is independent of your `find_machine` command. See below:
`progress = vm.launch_vm_process(session, 'gui', '')`
which basically launches that virtualbox.

I think that if your 'test_vm' machine really does exist (does it?? did you create it first in virtalbox?) it will be found just fine. Maybe just list your VMs first like I did:
`print("VM(s):\n + %s" % "\n + ".join([vm.name for vm in vbox.machines]))`
and then `find_machine` ? Or I have misunderstood what you're saying :p